# How can we implement an eval function case for the if-then-else expression in SML?

Tags: if-statement, eval, sml

How can we implement an eval function case for the if-then-else expression in SML? This subject in SML is challenging and new to me.

```
datatype exp = ...
  | Equal of exp * exp      
  | If of exp * exp * exp;

datatype value = BVal of bool | ...

fun print (Equal(x,y)) = "(" ^print(x)^ " = " ^print(y)^ ")"
  | print (If(x,y,z)) = "if " ^print(x)^ "
                         then " ^print(y)^ " else " ^print(z)
  | ...

fun eval (Equal(e1, e2)) ctx =
           let
                val (CVal x) = eval e1 ctx
                val (CVal y) = eval e2 ctx 
           in
                BVal (round x = round y)
           end
  | ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can we implement an eval function case for the if-then-else expression?

1. Make sure `CVal` is defined. It looks like it should be a part of `datatype value`, but it could also be defined in an area of the code that you have omitted. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when you post on StackOverflow, since too much guessing can lead to nonsensical answers.
2. Extend the `eval` function with pattern matching to handle the `If` constructor in a similar way as it already supports the `Equal` constructor.

Here is something that might get you started:

```ml
datatype value = BVal of bool | CVal of int (* replacing "..." *)

fun eval (Equal (e1, e2)) ctx =
    let
      val (CVal x) = eval e1 ctx
      val (CVal y) = eval e2 ctx 
    in
      BVal (round x = round y)
    end

  | eval (If (cond, e1, e2)) =
    let
      val ... = eval cond ctx
    in
      ...
    end
```

Depending on how you perform the pattern matching, you will want to pick `eval e1 ctx` or `eval e2 ctx` to be the result. You may want to look into the *case-of* construct here.